# What is the entropy associated with a diffusion process?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, diffusion, non-equilibrium

Is it possible to calculate entropy from the solution of a diffusion equation(with natural boundary conditions) by using the formula of Shanon entropy? Could anyone help me to understand the entropic perspective of a diffusion process?

Answer (score 2):

Consider purely diffusive particles evolving through
$$ \dot{x}_i(t)=\sqrt{2D}\xi(t)$$.
All of them with the same initial condition, $x(t=0)=x_0$. The density of these particles (or the probability distribution to find one of these particles in position ($x,t$) ) evolves through the Fokker-Planck equation
$$\partial_t P=D \partial_x^2 P,$$
with initial condition $P(x,t=0)=\delta(x-x_0)$.

The solution of the Fokker-Planck equation reads:
$$P(x,t|x(t=0)=x_0)=\frac{e^{\frac{x^2}{2Dt}}}{\sqrt{2D\pi t}}$$.

If you insert this solution in the formula for Shannon's entropy, you would have a time-varying entropy $S(t)$. At time $t=0$, the probability distribution is a Dirac delta, so the position of particles is exactly determined and entropy is zero $S(0)=S(t=0)=0$. In the limit of infinite time ($t\rightarrow \infty$), the probability distribution is uniform filling the whole accessible space with equal probability. That means that particles are completely delocalized and that entropy is maximum. Assuming that the particle is in a box of dimension $L$, the maximum entropy would read:
$$S(\infty)=\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}  S(t)\propto\log(L).$$
Basically $S(t)$ will be a monotonously increasing function connecting $S(0)$ and $S(\infty)$. As time goes on, particles are more delocalized and therefore the entropy grows until it is maximum. The state of maximum entropy can be seen as an equilibrium state, where all states are equally likely and there is no entropy production.

Comment: In the shanon entropy formula for t = 0, the entropy becomes negative infinity. We know at t=0 , the probablity distribution is a delta function. The the answer for entropy at this situation , should be 0. But then why it is negative infinity?

Comment: I find it easier to proof if you discretize space and think on P(x,t=0) as a Kronecker delta, $P(x,t=0)=\delta_{x,x_0}$. The entropy is the sum of P*log(P) evaluated for all possible values of x. Nevertheless, all values different from $x_0$ do not contribute to the sum. This is because $\lim_{y\to0} y \log(y)=0$. Therefore, the only value contributing to the entropy is precisely $x=x_0$, where the probability is one $P(x_0,t=0)=\delta_{x_0,x_0}=1$. Hence,  $S(t=0)=1\cdot log(1)=0$. In order to do this demonstration with continuous states, I guess you should use that $x=x_0$ has zero measure.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Javi's answer: if we use $$S(p(x))=-\int_D p(x) \log(p(x)) dx$$ over the domain D, and plug in $$p(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi D t}}e^{-x^2/4Dt}$$
we get
$$
S(p(x))=-\frac{1}{4\sqrt{\pi}}
\left[
\frac{x e^{-x^2/4\pi D t}}{\sqrt{Dt}}
- (2\pi \log(4\pi D t)+\pi) \text{erf}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{4\pi D t}}\right)
\right]_S.
$$
If we use $D=[-L,L]$ (and pointedly ignore that this makes the boundary value problem different from the one that gives the $p(x)$ - we can justify this by assuming large $L$) the result is
$$S(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} (\pi \log(4\pi D t)+\pi) \text{erf}\left(\frac{L}{\sqrt{4\pi D t}}\right).$$

The last factor approaches 1 for $L\gg \sqrt{4\pi D t} $, while the overall size of $S(t)$ grows logarithmically with $Dt$.

(There is some sloppiness here: to do this strictly you want to look at the differential entropy rather than the Shannon entropy and let $L\rightarrow \infty$, which gets rid of a divergence and those pesky little constant factors. )

Comment: In the shanon entropy formula for t = 0 becomes negative infinity. We know at t=0 , the probablity distribution is a delta function. The the answer for entropy at this situation , should be 0. But then why it is negative infinity?

Comment: That is part of the annoying divergences and why you need to use differential entropy rather than the Shannon entropy: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_entropy